# Tabulator 4.6, How Change row background color on a condition in Modern Theme

Tags: tabulator

I wish to change the background color with row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "green";
It is work with tabulator.min.css theme, but not work with the modern theme.

```
  <!--   <link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
      <link href="dist/css/tabulator_modern.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="user_data.json"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
<body>
    <div id="example-table"></div>
<script>
var local_data = esp_data;  
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {

    rowFormatter:function(row){
        //row - row component

        var bk = row.getData();

        if(bk["Beköltözhető "] == "igen"){
          row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
          // row.getElement().style.color = "green";

            console.log("bekötzheto");
        }
    },
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why it needs to be done differently than the normal css, but here is what you can do.

Instead of `row.getElement().style.backgroundColor`, you have to set it on the individual cells for the row.  So, `row.getElement().childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor` will set the first cell background to green.

Here is a working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/6wygod1c/10/